# How Localazy and Phrase Android SDk updating stings declaired in strings.xml over the air

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, sdk

I am working on an application where it is required that I have to change.update string resources declared in my String.xml file over the air without uploading a new version on stores. (From server)
Currently, it is already implemented by [Localazy](https://localazy.com/docs/android/localazy-gradle-plugin) and [Phrase](https://localazy.com/docs/android/localazy-gradle-plugin) Android SDK.

The client wants to update anything declared in the String.xml and for every local.

I have to do it for multiple languages. I have already implemented localization. But the app still requires dynamic changes in the String resources,

Answer (score 2):

As the author of this technology at [Localazy](https://localazy.com), I can explain it pretty well.

**How do we change strings.xml on the fly? We don't.**

[Our Gradle plugin](https://localazy.com/docs/android/localazy-gradle-plugin) adds [a library](https://localazy.com/docs/android/localazy-android-library) to your app, performs bytecode analysis, and routes all the relevant method calls through our library. The library itself acts as a proxy, updates its internal strings database from our servers, and serves updated strings whenever possible. It also calculates anonymous stats about string usage, etc., to optimize the translation process on the Localazy site.

All of this happens during the build time without ever touching your source code and resources. It's completely transparent.

While it sounds like a simple task, it's much more complicated as it's impossible to route all method calls easily. E.g., LayoutInflater uses a different method for obtaining strings, and the same applies to Preferences, Menus, etc.

We also download and merge your strings.xml with the latest translations available on Localazy as the standard system method is always a reasonable fallback. We must correctly handle edge cases such as language aliases (`iw` vs. `he`), RTL languages, etc.

One of the biggest challenges was correctly supporting build types, product flavors, libraries, and dynamic app modules. It's not just about serving strings from the internal database but selecting the right one. E.g., a string with the same key from a library has lower priority than the app's one. The situation is different for dynamic app modules.

We've designed Localazy to handle all of these situations from the ground - the library, how we store strings on our servers, etc.

It's not a simple task to do this correctly, so better use the existing solution if possible.

Feel free to ask me if you need further help.